# Cursor moves randomly

Tags: 13.04, cursor

I noticed that after a 1-hour (or longer) session, if I lock/suspend my laptop, when I start that session again, my cursor moves randomly and sometimes clicks as well. This does not happen on Windows (I have both Windows 7 and Ubuntu 13.04), so I know that it is not a hardware issue. It also happens when I use a USB mouse. I can fix it temporarily by turning my laptop off and booting in Ubuntu again, but this becomes tedious, especially because it's hard for me to shutdown while the cursor isn't completely in my control.

**Is there a way to fix this?**

---

I just noticed that even after restarting my laptop, the cursor continues to move on its own. It's also not only my account; in the Guest account and the login page itself, this continues to happen.

When I type in `xinput` in the Terminal, my mouse/touchpad/N-trig touchscreen are:

```
Virtual core pointer                        id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Dell Dell USB Optical Mouse               id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ N-Trig Touchscreen                        id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ N-Trig Pen stylus                         id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ N-Trig MultiTouch                         id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=18   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

Comment: Can you type `xinput` ina terminal, identify your mouse and touchpad and edit your post with the results?

Comment: @ToDo I added those in (along with my N-trig touchscreen).

Comment: Have you tried updating the firmware of your touchscreen? Go in Windows and try updating the firmware to the latest version. That might solve the problem.

Comment: Punch the person residing in the same room and steal his/her mouse. Seriously though, has it just "started happening" or is it a clean install?